# How to invoke block in NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, block

```c
NSMutableDictionary* actions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
actions[@"run"] = ^ () {
  NSLog(@"Hello");
};
actions[@"run"]();
```

Xcode reports the error `Called object type 'id' is not a function or function pointer` when I invoke the block in NSDictionary.

How I can invoke block stored in NSDictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a local variable to cast id to block type.

```
void(^block)(void) = [actions objectForKey:@"run"];
if(block)
{
   block();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is just a problem of cast,try the verbose version :

```
(void) (^dictBlock)(void)) = actions[@"run"];
dictClock()
```